# when i run the flutter project , it always noticed me that the following information

Tags: flutter

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed   Output:  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.1.0.aar/1ae061ef1f22c89af9cce652a74ed3e0/res/drawable/notification_tile_bg.xml:18: error: resource drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg) not found.   /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/jetified-lark-0.0.1-rc-9.aar/e1945b3b4377a2d4b6264edd5ed269f7/res/layout/activity_lark_sso.xml:14: error: resource drawable/lark_sso_ic_back (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/lark_sso_ic_back) not found.   /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/jetified-bdturing-1.2.0-cn.aar/06143809114432adc49b9930b2517d06/res/layout/layout_verify_dialog.xml:61: error: resource mipmap/ic_close_black_online (aka com.openlanguage.easy:mipmap/ic_close_black_online) not found.   /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/base-2.6.3.306.aar/6aa11138cf8c06d45d9a513b81a62186/res/layout/upsdk_app_dl_progress_dialog.xml:60: error: resource drawable/upsdk_cancel_normal (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/upsdk_cancel_normal) not found.   error: failed linking file resources.

  Command: /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/3d5386e66f8727e12a8f0d10ec1edc82/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
          --custom-package\
          com.openlanguage.easy\
          -0\
          apk\
          -c\
          zh-rCN,en\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0   Output:  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.1.0.aar/1ae061ef1f22c89af9cce652a74ed3e0/res/drawable/notification_tile_bg.xml:18: AAPT: error: resource drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/notify_panel_notification_icon_bg) not found.

  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/jetified-lark-0.0.1-rc-9.aar/e1945b3b4377a2d4b6264edd5ed269f7/res/layout/activity_lark_sso.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource drawable/lark_sso_ic_back (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/lark_sso_ic_back) not found.

  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/jetified-bdturing-1.2.0-cn.aar/06143809114432adc49b9930b2517d06/res/layout/layout_verify_dialog.xml:61: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_close_black_online (aka com.openlanguage.easy:mipmap/ic_close_black_online) not found.

  /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/base-2.6.3.306.aar/6aa11138cf8c06d45d9a513b81a62186/res/layout/upsdk_app_dl_progress_dialog.xml:60: AAPT: error: resource drawable/upsdk_cancel_normal (aka com.openlanguage.easy:drawable/upsdk_cancel_normal) not found.

  error: failed linking file resources.   Command: /Users/admin/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/3d5386e66f8727e12a8f0d10ec1edc82/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
          --custom-package\
          com.openlanguage.easy\
          -0\
          apk\
          -c\
          zh-rCN,en\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

**BUILD FAILED in 37s The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. 
The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility. 
Building plugin account... 
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...** 
***Finished with error: ProcessException: Permission denied***   Command:/Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/packages/account-0.0.4/android/gradlew
-I=/Users/bytedance/bd_flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/aar_init_script.gradle
-Pflutter-root=/Users/bytedance/bd_flutter -Poutput-dir=/Users/admin/Desktop/eo_client-1.0.0/build/app -Pis-plugin=true -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 assembleAarRelease
```

please somebody help me ,i have tried all kinds of methods these days , 
disappointedly, all of them were end of the failure.
I want to emphasis that i concentrated on the "**permission denied**", but another point - "**failed linking file resources**", i think it is also the key point of my error

At the same time , i have run it as super administrator  , and it worked!

```
sudo flutter run --device-id=3EP7N........
```

I have scanned many solutions before , and one of them thought it due to the computer permissions , is it really a problem with my own computer???
If anyone are willing to help me, I would appreciate it